# Проблема с оформлением окон в ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, шрифты, оформление

Слетели шрифты и оформление некоторых приложений в ubuntu 14.04.
Например:
Диалоговое окно сохранения файла в Atom:
[image: Диалоговое окно сохранения файла в Atom]
Внешний вид меню и вкладок в Firefox:
[image: Внешний вид меню и вкладок в Firefox]
Перед последним ребутом системы настраивал цвета директорий, выводимых *ls* в терминале (по аналогии с [этим ответом](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=764824&p=4779749#post4779749) на ubuntuforums.org)
Навряд ли это как-то связано, но на всякий случай откатил изменения, не помогло.

Как восстановить дефолтное оформление и шрифты?

P.S. Так же одновременно с этой проблемой появились следующие (может поможет с выявлением причины):
1. после входа в систему мышь не работает примерно 5 минут, потом начинает работать.
2. клавиатура работает, но *ctrl+shift+t* не работает тоже примерно 5 минут.

Comment: Заметил, что после того, как мышка начала работать, перезaпуск unity, командой `setsid unity` решает проблему. Буду разбираться почему не работает мышь при старте...

Comment: Проблема была в следующем: при старте системы возникала проблема инициализации USB устройств (клавиатура работала нормально т.к. PS/2), долго рыл интернет, пытаясь разобраться в проблеме, в итоге помогло обесточивание компьютера на некоторое время. После этого при старте системы проблем с USB уже не было, и оформление окон (например firefox) было нормальным. Видимо при возникновении ошибок с USB не выполнялись какие-то команды/скрипты при старте, связанные с работой unity.

Answer (score 1):

unity-tweak-tool позволяет переключать темы. Советую попробовать. Мммм... попробуй ещё откатить x-сервер до старой версии.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогла команда

```
setsid unity
```